# Using CSPlotter

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am trying to use [CSPlotter](https://math.aalto.fi/~fdahl/CSPlotter/), which is a way of visualizing the contact structure of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by plotting several sections of planes. It is written for an old version of Mathematica. I included the package code at the end. I tried to run

```
<<CSPlotter.m
xmin = -3.5; xmax = 3.5; dx = (xmax - xmin)/14;
ymin = -3.5; ymax = 3.5; dy = (ymax - ymin)/16;
size = dy;

normal[x_, y_, z_] = {-2y, 2x, 1};

Table[contactelement[{x, y, 0}, normal[x, y, 0], size], {x, xmin, 
   xmax, dx}, {y, ymin, ymax, dy}];
out = Show[%, coords[xmax + 1, ymax + 1, 3.4], Boxed -> False]
```

I get the error

```
Show: Could not combine the objects in
```

and it shows the separate planes that are created. It should produce a plot like this [image]

The CSPlotter code is here

```
Rotvect[v_] :=
  Module[
    {ex, ey, ez},
    If[v[[1]] == 0 && v[[2]] == 0,
     Return[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
      ]; 
    ez = v/Sqrt[v.v];
    ey = 1/Sqrt[v[[1]]^2 + v[[2]]^2] {-v[[2]], v[[1]], 0};
    ex = Cross[ey, ez];
    Transpose[{ex, ey, ez}]  
]

(*
 *  contactelement[disp, covect, scale]
 *   
 *  Returns a rectange centered at 'disp', normal to 'covect' 
 *  and of size 'scale' as a Mathematica Graphics3D object.
 *
 *)
contactelement[disp_, covect_, scale_] :=
  Module[
    {P, b1, b2, b3, b4},
    b1 = {-1/2, -1/2, 0}; b2 = {-1/2, 1/2, 0}; b3 = {1/2, 1/2, 0}; 
    b4 = {1/2, -1/2, 0};
    P = Rotvect[covect];
    gs = Graphics3D[Polygon[scale{ P.b1, P.b2, P.b3, P.b4}], Boxed -> False, 
        PlotRange -> All];
    gs = TranslateShape[gs, disp]
    ]


(*
 *  coords[xmax, ymax, zmax]
 *   
 *  returns (as a Mathematica Graphics3D object) coordinate
 *  axes of lengths 'xmax', 'ymax', and 'zmax', respectively. 
 *)

coords[xmax_, ymax_, zmax_] :=
  Graphics3D[
    {
      Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, zmax}}],
      Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, ymax, 0}}],
      Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {xmax, 0, 0}}],
      Text["x", {xmax + 0.25, 0, 0}],
      Text["y", {0, ymax + 0.25, 0}],
      Text["z", {0, 0, zmax + 0.25}]
    },
    PlotRange -> All]
```

I removed the lines that include 'Shapes.m' and 'VectorAnalysis.m' since Mathematica said it is built in to the current version. Is there a simple error I made in trying to use the package or can I modify the package so that it works in the newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove the `TranslateShape` and simply translate the coordinates by using

```
contactelement[disp_, covect_, scale_] := 
 Module[{P, b1, b2, b3, b4, gs}, b1 = {-1/2, -1/2, 0}; 
  b2 = {-1/2, 1/2, 0}; b3 = {1/2, 1/2, 0};
  b4 = {1/2, -1/2, 0};
  P = Rotvect[covect];
  Graphics3D[
   Polygon[scale (Plus[disp, #] & /@ {P.b1, P.b2, P.b3, P.b4})], 
   Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

I get

```
Show[Table[
  contactelement[
    {x, y, 0}, normal[x, y, 0], size], 
  {x, xmin, xmax, dx}, {y, ymin, ymax, dy}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]